# ¿Como capturar en una variable SESSION un elemento al dar click sobre el?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, sql

no se bien como expresar mi pregunta pero el asunto es este, estoy realizando un trabajo para un curso el cual estoy llevando pero estoy en un punto muerto, el trabajo basicamente consiste en realizar una "copia" sencilla de una red social, estos son los requisitos que nos pide el profesor:

1.Login/Registrar  por  usuario/clave  (Poblar  previamente  la  BD  con  al  menos  4  usuarios, cada uno con al menos 6 tuits.)

2.Todo usuario puede publicar un nuevo Tuit.

3.Un Tuit tiene: un usuario autor, hora de publicación y un cuerpo de mensaje que tiene un límite máximo de 140 caracteres.

4.Ver el timeline,  que  es  los  tuits  publicados en  orden  cronológico por  un usuario  al  seleccionar su nombre en uno de sus tuits.

5.Ver  timeline  general,  es  decir  todos  los  tuits  publicados  por  todos  los  usuarios,desplegados en orden cronológico.

El proyecto esta ya practicamente terminado el problema radica espeficicamente en que me quede atascado en el punto numero 4, para explicarme mejor ya logre mostrar el timeline general pero **lo que no logro hacer es que al hacer click sobre el nombre del usuario que publico ese tuit se muestren en otro php unicamente los tuist que fueron publicados por ese usuario.** Aqui les muestro el codigo para que me entiendan mejor:

Codigo PHP para mostrar todos los tuits:

Como pueden ver muestro el timeline dividiendo la consulta en rows, ahora el row['user'] lo converti en un link que me envia al otro php el cual deberia de mostrar los tuits de ese user pero aqui es donde tengo el problema ya que no se como capturar ese user para poder mandarlo en una varible al otro archivo php y que solo se me muestren sus tuits.

```
  session_start();          
  $servername =  "localhost";
  $password = "";
  $conn2 = mysqli_connect($servername,
  "root",$password,"php_tweet_database");

  $sql = 'SELECT user, publication, cuerpo FROM twett ORDER BY publication desc';
  $_SESSION['userbusqueda'] = array();  

  if ($result = mysqli_query($conn2, $sql)){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {               
      echo '<div>';
            echo '<div id="usarioBuscar" >';                 
            echo '<a href="../partials/individual.php?texto='.urlencode($row['user']).'">'.$row['user'].'</a>';                
            echo '</div>';
         echo '<div>';
            echo ''.$row["publication"].'';
          echo '</div>';

          echo '<div>';
            echo ''.$row["cuerpo"].'';
          echo '</div>';
          echo "<br>";
      echo '</div>';       
      $_SESSION['userbusqueda'] = $row['user'];   
    }         
  }
```

Codigo PHP para el timeline de un usuario:

Aqui basicamente lo que quiero hacer el poder traer desde el otro php el nombre del usuario al cual se le dio click en una variable para poder usarla dentro de la sentencia sql y que unicamente me muestre los tuits de ese usuario.

session_start();

```
$servername =  "localhost";
$password = "";
$conn2 = mysqli_connect($servername,
"root",$password,"php_tweet_database");

/*LA VARIABLE $VAL SOLO LA PUSE PARA MOSTRARLES DONDE IRIA LA VARIABLE          
QUE QUIERO LLAMAR DESDE EL OTRO PHP*/
$sql = "SELECT user, publication, cuerpo FROM twett WHERE user = '$val'";

if ($result = mysqli_query($conn2, $sql)){
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row["user"]."  ".$row["publication"]."<br>".$row["cuerpo"]."<br><br>";       
    }  
} else {
    echo "NO SE ENCONTRARON RESULTADOS";
}
```

Agradeceria mucho que me dieran ideas de como solucionar este problema, apenas estoy empezando en esto y la verdad es que mi profesor no es que ayude mucho.

Comment: estás cerca, tienes que pasar la variable en el link, prueba cambiar la variable texto por $val.. usa individual.php?val='.urlencode($row['user'])  en vez de individual.php?texto='.urlencode($row['user']).. ahora en tu archivo lo usas haciendo: $val = $_GET['val'];

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me solucionaste un dolor de cabeza de dias, no tenia idea de lo cerca que estaba jaja.

Comment: Excelente!!. Ahora estaba frente a un pc, así que respondí la pregunta como corresponde para que la cierres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código está cerca de lograr lo que necesitas. Tienes que pasar la variable al momento de generar el link que apunta a `../partials/individual.php`.

Puedes pasar la(s) variable(s) que necesites agregandola después del `?`. Actualmente estás pasando `texto` si quieres puedes renombrarla a `val`, después para usarla en tu archivo individual.php debes recibirla por GET:

Pasar la variable:

```
// ej1: pasar variable "texto" a tu archivo individual.php
echo '<a href="../partials/individual.php?texto='.urlencode($row['user']).'">'.$row['user'].'</a>';

// ej2: pasar variable con otro nombre ej. "val" a tu archivo individual.php
echo '<a href="../partials/individual.php?val='.urlencode($row['user']).'">'.$row['user'].'</a>';
```

Usar la variable:

```
// ej1
$val = $_GET['texto'];

// ej2
$val = $_GET['val'];
```